# How to flush "socket mobile" scanner buffer in IOS development?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, barcode-scanner

I have made an iOS Application using the Socket Mobile SDK. When I open my view, the scanner delegate receives data scanned before the viewdidload function.
How can I send a buffer reset or flush to the scanner?
I haven't found a function or command in ScanApiHelper library.

Comment: can you explain what you would like to do exactly ? because you can request to receive data any time , you can request after viewload and not before that ... please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your application should be able to do whatever it wants with the incoming data. If the application isn't ready to receive scans, can't it just ignore the data and maybe ask the user to scan again?